# does it have a function that change all NSStringEncoding into NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: macos, nsstringencoding

i want to download html code and save it to a html file.However, there are kinds of Encoding which are used into html files,such as NSUTF8StringEncoding,NSISOLatin1StringEncoding and so on. wethere it has a function that change the different files of encoding into the same,and when the webview load the html file,it looks like as normal.

Comment: Can you use [something like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding:)?

Comment: follow is my code:-(void)saveHtml:(NSString*)_html encoding:(NSStringEncoding)_encoding
{
    
    int contentLength = [_html lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:_encoding];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[_html cStringUsingEncoding:_encoding] length:contentLength];
    NSLog(@"data = %@",data);
    NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"****html = %@",html);
    
}      but the html is nothing